# No logro solucionar el error : TypeError: Object of type method-wrapper is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

```
# Import(s) #
import json
from chat import message_handler as me
import random
#############

mind = {"message": "null","mID": 0,"reply": "null"}


def learn(m):
    getMessage = m
    getReply = me.reply

    strReply = getReply.__str__

    mind["mID"] = random.randint(0,10000000)
    mind["message"] = getMessage
    mind["message"] = strReply

    with open("../data/TEMP.json", "w") as t:
        json.dump(mind, t)
    saveLearned()

def saveLearned():
    temp = open("../data/TEMP.json")
    brain = open("../data/conv.json")
    with open("../data/conv.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(temp, brain)
```

Tengo este codigo, se trata de un modulo para "aprender" nuevas respuestas a x comandos. Primero guarda el nuevo "fragmento" a escribir en un archivo temporal, para posteriormente pasarlo al archivo final ( asi tengo un pequeño registro y me mantego un poco mas informado de pequeños errores que puedan ocasionarse sin tener que buscar en el archivo final ). El problema es que al compilarlo me devuelve el error "TypeError: Object of type method-wrapper is not JSON serializable". Llevo un buen rato en busca de una solucion despues de haber probado muchas cosas.. pero no logro solucionarlo de manera correcta. Alguien podria ayudarme un poco? Al menos guiarme un poco, ando bastante perdido con este error y no encuentro una solucion conveniente.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración del error, no entendia muy bien lo de wrapper. Al momento de invocar learn() llamo a un String que contiene el mensaje que he escrito en consola. (En caso de que no exista el mensaje en el JSON lo que haria learn() es crearlo)

Comment: Ups, no me habia fijado en el "f.dump()", ya lo he cambiado a json. El error me lo da el primer dump, pero supongo que el segundo dump me daria el mismo error, solo que la ejecución se detiene con el primer dump debido al error.

Comment: Se me olvido mencionar en mi ultimo comentario la funcion de saveLearned(). El objetivo es hacer un dump entre TEMP.json y conv.json , los puse en constantes para aclarar el codigo un poco, los declare mal?

Comment: Ah, y creo que la fuente del error es que asignas `strReply = getReply.__str__` , cuando lo que querías hacer probablemente era `strReply = getReply.__str__()`. Tal como lo haces asignas _el método_ en lugar del resultado de llamarlo. En cualquier caso no es habitual invocar los métodos "dunder" (los que van flanqueados por `__`). Una forma más estándar de hacer lo mismo sería `strReply = str(getReply)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas pasando algo que no es un json ya que le pasas la variable temp que no es mas que el archivo no lo que contiene para ello usas el metodo read()

```
# Import(s) #
import json
from chat import message_handler as me
import random
#############

mind = {"message": "null","mID": 0,"reply": "null"}


def learn(m):
    getMessage = m
    getReply = me.reply

    strReply = getReply.__str__

    mind["mID"] = random.randint(0,10000000)
    mind["message"] = getMessage
    mind["message"] = strReply

    with open("../data/TEMP.json", "w") as t:
        json.dump(mind, t)
    saveLearned()

def saveLearned():
    #leer el archivo con el metodo read()
    temp = open("../data/TEMP.json").read()
    #brain = open("../data/conv.json")
    with open("../data/conv.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(temp, f)
```

Comment: @guskikalola No me explico por qué esta respuesta está aceptada. No sólo sigue teniendo el mismo problema que ya tenía el código original (cuya explicación he dado en unos comentarios a la pregunta) sino que la parte que se "arregla" tampoco funcionaría, ya que está usando `json.dump()` para volcar algo que no es json, sino una cadena...

Answer (score 1):

Primero la **explicación del error**. Te dice `TypeError: Object of type method-wrapper is not JSON serializable` lo que básicamente significa que uno de los campos del diccionario que quieres volcar como JSON no es "serializable", es decir, que no es una lista, cadena, número, u otro diccionario o algo que pueda tratarse como tal. Es más, te dice que el problema es que es de tipo `method-wrapper`, o sea, una función (en particular, una función no implementada en tu programa, sino importada desde un módulo, o parte de los *builtins* de python, que está programado en C).

Segundo el **lugar donde cometes tu error**, que es en la línea que dice:

```
strReply = getReply.__str__
```

Eso asigna a `strReply` el atributo `__str__` de `getReply`, pero ese atributo no es la representación como cadena, que es lo que parece que pensabas. Es un método que *convierte* en cadena al objeto `getReply`. Pero en tu asignación no estás invocando a ese método (pues faltarían los paréntesis como en `getReply.__str__()`) y por tanto lo que asignas es directamente una referencia al método. Precisamente el `method-wrapper` del que luego se queja `json.dump()`.

Se resuelve añadiendo los paréntesis que faltaban en la llamada, pero mejor aún usando esta otra sintaxis más estándar:

```
strReply=str(getReply)
```

Finalmente **sobre la función `saveLearned()`**. Si el objetivo de esta función es copiar el contenido de un fichero en otro, puede ser mucho más simple que hagas:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile("../data/TEMP.json", "../data/conv.json")
```

ya que, sin importar si el contenido de los ficheros es json o cualquier otra cosa, todo lo que estás haciendo es copiar lo que hay en un fichero al otro.

Tu intento de usar el módulo `json` por el medio (y la respuesta de Bryo) causaría que el fichero resultante `conv.json` acabe teniendo una cadena de caracteres con un JSON dentro, en lugar de un JSON válido.

Pero si insistes en usar `json`, entonces deberías usarlo tanto para leer como para escribir, así:

```
def saveLearned():
    temp = open("../data/TEMP.json")
    brain = open("../data/conv.json")
    data = json.load(temp)
    json.dump(brain, data)
```